# How do I cleanly read a property in an unknown error thrown?

Tags: javascript, typescript, try-catch

In the new 4.0 release of TS, [we can now typed error as unknown](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#unknown-on-catch).

Before, this code was ok because `err` was typed as `any`:

```
catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
}
```

In TS 4.0, we can typed `err` as `unknown`, but the code won't compiled

```
catch (err: unknown) {
    console.error(err.message); // Error: Object is of type 'unknown'
}
```

So we can manually typed it with the `as` keyword:

```
catch (err: unknown) {
    const typedError = err as { message: string };
    console.error(typedError.message);
}
```

But this feels dirty, the `as` keyword is not a safe keyword, and the developer can still miss a lot of cases. What if `err` is null for example?

I tried something like that, but it doesn't works:

```
catch (err: unknown) {
    if(err && typeof err === 'object' && 'message' in err) {
        console.error(err.message); // Error: Property 'message' does not exist on type 'object'
    }
}
```

What is the cleanest and safe way to read a property from an `unknown` object? (No `as` keyword, full typesafety)

Related links:

- [treat `in` operator as type guard which asserts property existence](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21732)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to check the options, and it seems your approach is quite good. Here is what I have:

```js
const hasMessage = (err: any): err is {message: string} =>
    err && typeof err === 'object' && "message" in err;

try {
    // Some code here
} catch (err: unknown) {
    // Just to catch all 'standard' errors
    if (err instanceof Error) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }

    // Use a typeguard for 'err' (just tell the compiler, that it has 'message')
    if (hasMessage(err)) {
        console.error(err.message);
    }

    // Your original 'if', but with a typecast inside
    // (because we are sure it has 'message' in 'err')
    if (err && typeof err === 'object' && "message" in err) {
        const typedError = err as { message: string };
        console.error(typedError.message);
    }
}
```